# compare two seperate pandas dataframes row by row and return matching values

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas data frames df1 and df2. df1 contains 2 columns and 750 rows, df2 has 2 columns and 88 rows. I want to compare the two data frames and return the values from df1 that are present in df2 and store the matching values in a new column in df2.
Ex.

```
df1

    A            B
    emp_table    emp_id
    emp_table    emp_name 
    pay_table    basic_amount
    pay_table    da_amount

df2
A              B
emp_table      emp_id
emp_table      emp_department
pay_table      da_amount
```

I want to add another column in df2 which has the matching values.

```
df2
A           B
emp_table   emp_id
pay_table   da_amount
```

I want to perform one to many comparison of each element of df1 with each element of df2.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) without parameter `on`, so all columns are joined:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2)
print (df)
           A          B
0  emp_table     emp_id
1  pay_table  da_amount
```

Comment: The merge function does not show  any matches. I want to find the matches between the two dataframe.

Comment: @Vishwa Do you test it with sample data from question?